# display data in flexible columns rather than rows in php

Tags: php

I want to show data from database in columns rather than in rows. This code only works fine when number of both column items are equal. when they are odd it shows an error of undefined offset.

```
    | 1 | 5 |
    | 2 | 6 |
    | 3 | 7 |
    | 4 |  
    $mid = ceil(mysqli_num_rows($result)/2);
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) )
         {$list[] = $row; 
          }
     for( $i = 0; $i < $mid; $i++ ) {
        $itemOne = $list[$i];
        $itemTwo = $list[$i + $mid]; 
    
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>
       <button name='city'>".$itemOne[1]."</button>
                </td>   
<td>
       <button>".$itemTwo[1]."</button>         
        </td>
         </tr>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `mysqli_num_rows($result) = 7` and `$mid = 4`.

The iteration starting from 0, so the 1st couple is (0,4), the 2nd is (1,5), and so on until (3,7). But 7 is illegal index! you have only 0-6.

A good correction should be to check `isset($list[$i + $mid])`, and if not - assign to `$itemTwo` a placeholder value.

Comment: in odd number of element/data "$itemTwo" remain empty and its shows an error of undefined index. plz kindly give me the solution of this problem

Comment: In odd number case you should not have 2 buttons in the last row